# How to integrate signed URL in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dolby

I am trying to use`DOLBY.IO's media API` to transcode and save the output file to cloud. I have two URLs  {URL1:input to dolby; URL2: to store output from dolby}. And both the URLs are signed URLs from the same cloud.

I tried using some java code to accomplish this but in the end I still can't get the result.

Here is the code:

```
@PostMapping("/transcode")
    public String Video_Transcode1() throws IOException, JSONException {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        String data=generate_Access_token( );
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\"inputs\":[{\"source\":\"https://vb-object-storage.ap-south-1.linodeobjects.com/The%20Hindu%20Daily%20News%20Analysis%20__%203rd%20July%202022%20__%20UPSC%20Current%20Affairs%20__%20Prelims%20%2722%20%26%20Mains%20%2722%28360%29.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220707T073322Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=604799&X-Amz-Credential=ZVADROBVHWLK1FOYT225%2F20220707%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=0aa4b388ea3197dd8a03253f5f7313b4209b8acf5e0a4308dc5e543801d22c73\"}],\"outputs\":[{\"kind\":\"mp4\",\"destination\":\"https://vb-object-storage.ap-south-1.linodeobjects.com/The%20Hindu%20Daily%20News%20Analysis%20__%203rd%20July%202022%20__%20UPSC%20Current%20Affairs%20__%20Prelims%20%2722%20%26%20Mains%20%2722%28360%29.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220707T073322Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=604799&X-Amz-Credential=ZVADROBVHWLK1FOYT225%2F20220707%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=0aa4b388ea3197dd8a03253f5f7313b4209b8acf5e0a4308dc5e543801d22c73\"}]}");
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
          .url("https://api.dolby.com/media/transcode")
          .post(body)
          .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
          .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
          .addHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+data)
          .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        return response.toString();
    }
```

Here the data is generated from another function (ie:Access token)

I have encoded two URLs as json here:

```
 RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\"inputs\":[{\"source\":\"https://vb-object-storage.ap-south-1.linodeobjects.com/The%20Hindu%20Daily%20News%20Analysis%20__%203rd%20July%202022%20__%20UPSC%20Current%20Affairs%20__%20Prelims%20%2722%20%26%20Mains%20%2722%28360%29.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220707T073322Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=604799&X-Amz-Credential=ZVADROBVHWLK1FOYT225%2F20220707%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=0aa4b388ea3197dd8a03253f5f7313b4209b8acf5e0a4308dc5e543801d22c73\"}],\"outputs\":[{\"kind\":\"mp4\",\"destination\":\"https://vb-object-storage.ap-south-1.linodeobjects.com/The%20Hindu%20Daily%20News%20Analysis%20__%203rd%20July%202022%20__%20UPSC%20Current%20Affairs%20__%20Prelims%20%2722%20%26%20Mains%20%2722%28360%29.mp4?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220707T073322Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=604799&X-Amz-Credential=ZVADROBVHWLK1FOYT225%2F20220707%2Fap-south-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=0aa4b388ea3197dd8a03253f5f7313b4209b8acf5e0a4308dc5e543801d22c73\"}]}");
```

Is there any look around to bring the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like both signed URLs might be GET urls?

For the Dolby.io Transcode API, your `inputs` should be GET signed urls and your `outputs` should be PUT signed URLs.

Additionally, it also looks like you are using the same input path/filename and output path/filename:

```
https://vb-object-storage.ap-south-1.linodeobjects.com/The%20Hindu%20Daily%20News%20Analysis%20__%203rd%20July%202022%20__%20UPSC%20Current%20Affairs%20__%20Prelims%20%2722%20%26%20Mains%20%2722%28360%29.mp4
```

You will want to use different paths for input and output, something like:

`https://vb-object-storage.ap-south-1.linodeobjects.com/output/outputfile.mp4`

(note the "output" added to the path and the change of the output filename)